# Web api: The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I created an API controller on my MVC4 project

Here is the method I created to test the functionality of the API

```
private string Login(int id)
{
    Employee emp = db.Employees.Find(id);
    return emp.Firstname;
}
```

When I try to access this api with `localhost:xxxx/api/controllerName/Login?id=2`, I get

> {"$id":"1","Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

What am I doing wrong?

Also, here is my api config file

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
```

Comment: Start by making the method public

Comment: @GiorgioMinardi, continue by `[HttpGet] // Or [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` ...

Comment: @giorgio Minardi, @ gdoron Oh. thanks guys. my bad. so sorry to bother the community with something so trival. It works now, but i was expecting it to give me result in d format "Firstname:john". it just gives "john". is this the normal behaviour?

Comment: It returns "john" because you are returning a string, so you get back a JSON-serialized string. If you want an object with a property FirstName, you need to return an object with that property.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change the method modifier from private to public, also add the relevant accept verbs to the action

```
private string Login(int id)
```

Change to:

```
[HttpGet] // Or [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public string Login(int id)
```

Comment: my method is classified as `public` but still, I am facing this error.

Comment: @Vijayaraghavan post your code and you can ping me if no ones help. I'm sure you will get the answer in matter of minutes.

Comment: @gdoron issue resolved after hosting my API domain under `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`. earlier API was hosted using dummy SSL certificate. this could be the reason. waiting for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can also accept http methods in web.config inside system.webserver tag:

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to the question.
These headers add CORS information to the response.
They specify which HTTP Methods a client might be allowed to use when doing a CORS request.
The MVC Methods however are managed on the server side.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the currently accepted answer of adding the `[HttpGet]` attribute to make the method public, you need to make sure you are using the right namespace:

- MVC controllers use `System.Web.Mvc`
- WebAPI controllers use `System.Web.Http`

Comment: Thanks, this helped in resolving my issue, I spent hours figuring out why it wasn't hitting my Controller